# Seeding the site

Tags: discussion, seeding-questions

I'm having a small issue on how the site should be seeded.

I recently asked a "seed" question: [How do I get the cake in Portal?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/546/how-do-i-get-the-cake-and-not-die)

Obviously I know the answer but it seems like the type of question that would be asked, hence the seeding.

Am I incorrect in my thinking?

Comment: It might be the type of question that would be asked, but it's also the kind of question that would be closed. We should be treating the private beta as if it's launched in my opinion.

Comment: Yep. A very fair point. :)

Comment: On this particular seed question, a perfectly valid formulation would have been about "how to escape the fire during the last test room"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seeding the site is not about filling it with random junk questions. You should basically think of any question you've ever had about the game or a question that someone else has had(that is not already here) and ask it and/or answer it.

The point is that every question should have a purpose.

EDIT:

Also, if your question was a bit less jokey sounding(and not following a meme) then it may have stayed open. It looked like a joke question upon first inspection to me

Comment: Fair enough. I did kinda have fun writing it... maybe too much fun :P